# How to sum value in column and display it?

Tags: php

I have database named `testing` and I create table named `countme`

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++

++ ID +++ Click ++++++++

++ 1  +++ 10 +++++++++++

++ 2  +++ 8  +++++++++++

++ 3  +++ 2  +++++++++++

++ 4  +++ 21 +++++++++++
```

How to count column `Click` and display it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Mysql `sum()` function.

Example:

```
SELECT SUM(`Click`) FROM countme
```

Comment: this is useful for me

Answer (score 1):

Try this SQL

```
SELECT SUM(`Click`) AS total FROM `countme`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SUM()` in SQL statement,

`select SUM(Click) as ClickTotal from countme`

Ref: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum